# Default nmap script execution when specifying --script banner

Tags: nmap, nse

I have a subscription for a NSE scripts feed for nmap. There are some of those scripts which have the default category (among others)

I am running nmap in the following way

```
nmap --privileged -oX - -T3 -O --osscan-guess --max-os-tries=1 -sV -sS --script banner -PP -PE -PM -PI <ip_address>
```

However, what I am observing is that I am not getting only the output for the banner script, but for multiple other scripts which, as you can see, I am not requesting to be executed.

AFAIK, the scripts which are executed can be specified with the name or with the category. In this case, I am specifying the name, so not sure why other scripts are also run.

Does anybody have any idea about the cause for this?

Comment: What scripts are being run? Are they all "banner" type scripts? Have you checked to see that you are calling the script name correctly?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? If you remove the `--script` part, do those scripts still run? If you remove all the other options, which tend to run multiple tools, does the problem still occur? My guess is that you are misinterpretting what a script running is and the outputs of all the other things you have going on in that command.